# Poll question which adds the correct amount of reactions. (d.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a poll command which adds the correct amount of reactions such as A B C D E etc.

I have already tried this but it was a simple yes or no poll command.

```
elif message.content.startswith('m/qpoll'):
    question = message[8:]
    await message.delete()
    message = await message.channel.send(f"**New poll:** {question}")
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.add_reaction('✔️')
```

What i am trying to achieve is a command which adds A B C reactions if there is three possible answers and A B C D E if there is five possible answers etc.

The command the user has to use is preferred to be in this format:
`m/poll "question" "answer 1" "answer 2" "answer 3"`

The command needs to be under a `on_message` statement as the command package does not work as well for my bot.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it, without using `discord.ext.commands` :

```py
elif message.content.startswith('m/qpoll'):
    content = message.content[8:]
    items = content.split(" ")
    question = items[0]
    answers = '\n'.join(items[1:])

    await message.delete()
    message = await message.channel.send(f"**New poll:** {question}\n{answers}")
    reactions = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] #replace the letters with your reactions

    for i in range(len(items[1:]))
        await message.add_reaction(reactions[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the poll command I made for my bot

````
    @commands.command()
    async def poll(self, ctx):
        """
        Conduct a poll (interactive)
        ?poll
        """
        member = ctx.author
        member: Member
        maker = []
        await ctx.send("```What is the Question ❓```")
        em = ["", "", "", "️", ""]

        def mcheck(m):
            return m.author == member

        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=20.0, check=mcheck)
            maker.append(msg.content)
        except TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send("```Poll timed out ⏳```")

        await ctx.send("```How many options do you want?```")
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=20.0, check=mcheck)
        except TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send("```Poll timed out ⏳```")

        i = int(msg.content)
        if i > 5:
            return await ctx.send("```A maximum of 5 options for polls```")
        await ctx.send("```Enter your options ✔```")
        for i in range(i):
            try:
                await ctx.send(f"```{i + 1}) ```")
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=20.0, check=mcheck)
                maker.append(msg.content)
                await msg.add_reaction("✅")
            except TimeoutError:
                return await ctx.send("```Poll timed out ⏳```")
        poller = Embed(color=0x5EE34)
        poller.title = maker[0]
        des = ''
        for j in range(1, len(maker)):
            des += f"```{em[j - 1]} {maker[j]}```\n"
        poller.description = des
        pr = await ctx.send(embed=poller)
        for j in range(i + 1):
            await pr.add_reaction(em[j])

        def reac_check(r, u):
            return pr.id == r.message.id and r.emoji in em

        eopt = {e: 0 for e in em}
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20.0, check=reac_check)
                e = str(reaction.emoji)
            except TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("```Poll Finished ✅```")
                break
            if e in eopt.keys() and user != self.bot.user:
                eopt[e] += 1

        eopt = {k: v for k, v in sorted(eopt.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
        most = next(iter(eopt))
        loc = em.index(most)
        poller.title = "Results "
        poller.description = f"```Folks chose \n{maker[loc + 1]}```"
        return await ctx.send(embed=poller)
````

As a rule of thumb avoid using `on_message` to create commands. You can read about commands.Bot() in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot).
That said you should be able adapt the above example to suit your needs.